# Random array from list of arrays by numpy.random.choice()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have list of arrays similar to `lstB` and want to pick random collection of 2D arrays. The problem is that numpy somehow does not treat objects in lists equally:

```
lstA = [numpy.array(0), numpy.array(1)]
lstB = [numpy.array([0,1]), numpy.array([1,0])]

print(numpy.random.choice(lstA))   # returns 0 or 1
print(numpy.random.choice(lstB))   # returns ValueError: must be 1-dimensional
```

Is there an ellegant fix to this?

Comment: Any reason not to use the std. lib. `random.choice` function rather than NumPy's? Alternatively, you could use `np.random.randint` to generate a suitable index.

Comment: It is possible, but not convenient for more than one element to pick.

Comment: If you want to pick an object from a list, `random.choice` is the obvious choice. `numpy.random.choice` is for sampling from 1-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Do you want to pick [with replacement or without replacement](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call it semi-elegant...

```
# force 1d object array
swap = lstB[0]
lstB[0] = None
arrB = np.array(lstB)
# reinsert value
arrB[0] = swap
# and clean up
lstB[0] = swap
# draw
numpy.random.choice(arrB)
# array([1, 0])
```

Explanation: The problem you encountered appears to be that numpy when converting the input list to an array will make as deep an array as it can. Since all your list elements are sequences of the same length this will be 2d. The hack shown here forces it to make a 1d array of object dtype instead by temporarily inserting an incompatible element.

However, I personally would not use this. Because if you draw multiple subarrays with this method you'll get a 1d array of arrays which is probably not what you want and tedious to convert.

So I'd actually second what one of the comments recommends, i.e. draw ints and then use advanced indexing into `np.array(lstB)`.